# html5 Image wont load

Tags: html, image, duplicates

Hopefully I wont need to supply a lot of code for this. 
I am placing an image onto a page easily enough. Yet when I copy the image, rename it and supply the appropriate html, it doesn't load. I'm sure I will work around this but it is the 'why' that is seriously confusing me.

```
<body>
<img src="kitten1.jpg" alt="kitten1">
<img src="kitten2.jpg" alt="kitten2">
</body>
```

kitten2 is a renamed copy of kitten1 and is found in the same folder

[image]

Comment: Inspect the image element, right click the URL and open in new tab. If it doesn't load there, remove the filename and see the directory listing. Find your image there and see if the URL is any different than what you expect

Comment: Maybe you have a space in your file name when you have renamed it? Try to access it directly in a new tab.